# UILabel prevents UIButton from being shown until you continue from debug view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a stack view with 3 arranged subviews; a button with a checkbox image, a label with some text and another button with an 'i' image. When the view is created the last button isn't shown for some reason, so I go to debug view hierarchy, where I can see the button in the list of views but nowhere in the actual view. When I then press continue to stop debugging the view hierarchy, the button all of a sudden shows up and squeezes the label a bit so it fits.

If I remove the label, both buttons are shown just fine. If I put the views in a UIView instead of a stack view the 'i' button is not shown. If I shorten the text on the label, the 'i' button is shown correctly. EDIT: I also tried switching the label and the 'i' button and then both are shown correctly as well.

[image: Before debugging]

[image: After debugging]

Do you know what methods are called when you continue from debugging that could change the views? Do you know another way to solve this issue?

Thanks

EDIT: Stackviews constraints are just superviews constrainst with some inset constants:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 12),
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 12),
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 10)
])
```

The buttons and label are just added as arranged subviews with no added constraints

Comment: In your storyBoard, set your stack view Distribution property to fill equally .. and set your label auto shrink property to minimum font size etc ..11

Comment: Please share screenshot with contraints on/in stack view if any

Comment: edited to show constraints

Comment: why do you have a bottom constraint for your stackView? let the stackView decides the height it self if the buttons are small

Comment: Are you setting up this view (instantiating the elements, adding them, setting constraints, etc) on a background thread? That *might* be the reason you would see differences between letting the code run and interrupting it with debugging. Maybe show the full code you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the StackView go to **Attributes Inspector** check if Alignment = **fill & Distribution = fill** Now select the **label** inside the **StackView** go to **Size Inspector** find content **Hugging priority & content Compression Resistance Priority** the Horizontal priority to less than 250 So the label can easily be stretched and pressed back

**Update:**

I added 2 buttons and a label I just used text and colour in the buttons to simulate what you need.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let label = UILabel()
    let checkmarkButton = UIButton()
    let infoButton = UIButton()

    label.text = "Jeg acceptere vilkår og betinging"
    label.setContentHuggingPriority(240.0, for: .horizontal)
    label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(240, for: .horizontal)
    label.textAlignment = .center


    checkmarkButton.setTitle("Check", for: .normal)
    checkmarkButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    infoButton.setTitle("info", for: .normal)
    infoButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray


    view.addSubview(label)
    view.addSubview(checkmarkButton)
    view.addSubview(infoButton)



    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [checkmarkButton, label, infoButton])
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.distribution = .fill




    view.addSubview(stackView)

    // You have set the trailing constant to 12 which is going outside of the screen if you want to set the trailingAnchor constant programmatically it should be negative
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 80),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 12)
        ])

}
```

Comment: I am working programatically but I tried setting all those as you suggest and it didn't change anything, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: do you have proper constraint for the stackView?

Comment: Ah, first time I missed the setContentCompressionResistancePriority,  that made the difference, thanks a lot!!